# Load XML configuration files from specific path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Suppose the following structure:

```
 - /app/
    - someJARfile.jar/
        - BOOT-INF/lib/innerJARfile.jar/
            - META-INF/spring/applicationContext-A.xml
    - libs/
        - aJARfile.jar/
            - META-INF/spring/applicationContext-A.xml
            - META-INF/spring/applicationContext-S.xml
        - bJARfile.jar/
            - META-INF/spring/applicationContext-A.xml
```

and suppose want to import **only** Spring configuration defined in JAR files inside libs/ folder (aJARfile and bJARfile, but not configuration defined in innerJARfile). Cannot change file names because is third-party.

I tried the following:

```
@ImportResource ("classpath*:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-*.xml")
public class Application {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
    app.run(args);
}
```

But the above code is also loading Spring configuration defined in xml file of innerJARfile.

Also I tried:

```
@ImportResource ("file:/app/libs/*/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-*.xml")
public class Application {...}
```

But using prefix "file:" makes that do not load any Spring configuration xml files (import process see JAR files of /app/libs folder, but not inside JAR files, then any file match the pattern).

I am considering the option of doing it programmatically.

Is it possible to load the Spring configuration xml files that exist only in libs folder?

Comment: No as they are all part of the classpath so all of those files will be loaded with your current pattern. Why not just remove the one for `someJARfile.jar` as that seems to be your Spring Boot application in the first place or move to Java configuration which is a lot easier to exclude and manipulate.

Comment: Sorry @M.Deinum, I edit the structure. Actually the configuration file which I don't want to load is not in my SpringBoot application, but in third-party library which is included as fat jar (.../BOOT-INF/lib/innerJARfile.jar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it programatically.

Listen Spring Boot ApplicationPreparedEvent:

```
public class Application {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
    app.addListeners(new CustomImportResources());
    app.run(args);
}
```

and load beans from resources that exist only in /app/libs/ folder:

```
public class CustomImportResources implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationPreparedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent (ApplicationPreparedEvent event) {
        List<Resource> libsConfigFiles;
        Pattern libsPattern = Pattern.compile("file:/app/libs/.*");
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = event.getApplicationContext();
        
        try {
            Resource[] configFiles = context.getResources("classpath*:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-*.xml");
            libsConfigFiles = Stream.of(configFiles).filter(r -> {
                try {
                    return libsPattern.matcher(r.getURL().getPath()).matches();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }).toList();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    
        System.out.println("Loading bean definitions from configuration files: " + libsConfigFiles);
        for (Resource libConfigFile : libsConfigFiles) {
            XmlBeanDefinitionReader xmlReader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader((GenericApplicationContext) context);
            xmlReader.setValidationMode(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.VALIDATION_AUTO);
            xmlReader.loadBeanDefinitions(libConfigFile);
        }
    }
}
```